# Firebase - Why isnt search for users working in my app? (updating the searchcontroller when user has typed two letters)

Tags: swift, firebase, uitableview, uisearchcontroller

i have had this issue for a long time. The only way my searchUsers function work is when i put it in ViewDidLoad, and then change the .count to be equal or less than 0 (because its 0 by default).

But as it is right now (how i think it should work), the search dosent work.

What i want it to do is :

1. Only start the firebase search for users when the user has typed at least two letters (so it only searches for the users when the user has started typing, and only showing and loading the relevant data).
2. Also update the tableview along with filtering the search.

This is my code:

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseDatabase
import Firebase
import SDWebImage
import ObjectMapper

class FollowUsersTableViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!

    private var viewIsHiddenObserver: NSKeyValueObservation?
    let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    var usersArray = [UserModel]()
    var filteredUsers = [UserModel]()
    var loggedInUser: User?
    //
    var databaseRef = Database.database().reference()
    //usikker på den koden over

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()

        //large title
        self.title = "Discover"
        if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
            self.navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
        } else {
            // Fallback on earlier versions
        }

        self.tableView?.delegate = self
        self.tableView?.dataSource = self
        searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
        searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        self.searchController.delegate = self;

        definesPresentationContext = true
        tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar

        //self.loadProfileData()

       //self.searchBar(searchController.searchBar, textDidChange: searchController.searchBar.text)
    }

    func searchUsers(text: String) {
        if text.count >= 2 {
            self.usersArray = [] //clear the array each time
            let endingText = text + "\u{f8ff}"
            databaseRef.child("profile").queryOrdered(byChild: "username")
                .queryStarting(atValue: text)
                .queryEnding(atValue: endingText)
                .observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in

                    for child in snapshot.children {
                        let childSnap = child as! DataSnapshot
                        print(childSnap)
                        let userObj =  Mapper<UserModel>().map(JSONObject: childSnap.value!)
                        userObj?.uid = childSnap.key
                        if childSnap.key != self.loggedInUser?.uid { //ignore this user
                            self.usersArray.append(userObj!)

                        }
                    }
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                })
        }
    } //may need an else statement here to clear the array when there is no text

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        let dest = segue.destination as! UserProfileViewController
        let obj = sender as! UserModel
        let dict = ["uid": obj.uid!, "username": obj.username!, "photoURL": obj.photoURL, "bio": obj.bio]
        dest.selectedUser = dict as [String : Any]
    }
}

// MARK: - tableview methods
extension FollowUsersTableViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return searchController.searchBar.text!.count >= 2 ? filteredUsers.count : 0
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! FollowTableViewCell

        let user = filteredUsers[indexPath.row]

        cell.title?.text = user.username
        if let url = URL(string: user.photoURL ?? "") {
            cell.userImage?.sd_setImage(with: url, placeholderImage: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "user_male"), options: .progressiveDownload, completed: nil)
            cell.userImage.sd_setIndicatorStyle(.gray)
            cell.userImage.sd_showActivityIndicatorView()
        }

        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 50
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "user", sender: self.filteredUsers[indexPath.row])
    }
}

// MARK: - search methods
extension FollowUsersTableViewController:UISearchResultsUpdating, UISearchControllerDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate {

    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar,
                   textDidChange searchText: String) {

        self.searchUsers(text: searchText)
    }

    func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
        searchController.searchResultsController?.view.isHidden = false
        filterContent(searchText: self.searchController.searchBar.text!)

        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }

    func filterContent(searchText:String){
        if searchText.count >= 2{
            self.filteredUsers = self.usersArray.filter{ user in
                return(user.username!.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased()))
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: When you say 'the search doesn't work' what does that mean? Is the searchUsers function called at all? Is Firebase not returning results? Can you please clarify what isn't working and provide some details about where things are going wrong?

Comment: Hello again Jay. Thanks for your previous help, but im kind of still stuck on this. The function does print the snapshot (so it does actually search), but nothing gets displayed in the tableview.

Comment: Also, for some weird reason , when i search Ma , it only prints the info of user "Makalai", and does not print user "Mattgilbert". I dont know why this happens?

Comment: but my main issue , is that the tableview is empty, even though the info shows up in console

Comment: Do you have a thought on whats wrong my friend?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set

```
searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
```

You conform to `UISearchResultsUpdating` and implement `updateSearchResults` but it doesn't call `func searchUsers(text: String)`

and conform to `UISearchControllerDelegate` that has no relation to the search look to it's methods [Here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uisearchcontrollerdelegate)

Comment: Where should i set it? i think ill set it as self

Comment: try to move  self.searchUsers(text: searchText) to updateSearchResults

Comment: Still dosent work , when i add `self.searchUsers(text: self.searchController.searchBar.text!)` to `func updateSearchResults`

Comment: i think the console prints the name, as it did before, but it still dosent show in tableview